# Respond.js for CSS3 Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use Respond.js for CSS3 Media Queries on older IE versions 
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

I am getting some Access denied message in Javascript.

I have tried similar to
http://scottjehl.github.com/Respond/cross-domain/example.html

I think there are some cross-domain setup to be done...But I am not sure why that is needed. I just need to test everything locally as of now.
So I have all the files locally...Please help me fix this issue.

Any other suggestions for similar easy-to-use library would also be fine..

Comment: Are you using a local web server?

Comment: No..I am just testing on local hard disk..it is an html file..

Comment: you will definitely get cross-domain issues if you mix local files and http files in the same page. Web browsers are quite strict about this because if they weren't it would be very easy for a malicious site to include arbitrary files from your local hard drive and then examine the contents.

Comment: So how do I fix this and can this be fixed to not include http request at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you state that you're running the test on your local hard disk.

According to the [Repond.js documentation](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), you will have issues with this:

> Due to security restrictions, some browsers may not allow this script to work on file:// urls (because it uses xmlHttpRequest). Run it on a web server.

So if you're just loading pages from your C: drive, you will need to install a localhost web server to get it working.

Additionally, even if you are running on a web server, if the respond.js file is on a different domain (or subdomain) from your main page, then you will need to do some cross-domain setup.

Again, this is documented; see the section in the documentation entitled "CDN/X-Domain Setup". It includes examples, and references an example file available with the source.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to like loading files using protocol relative paths such as //fast.fonts.com/cssapi/dssdc20a-sa33-4775-8559-db2ssdb955d.css